# How do I solve this error that shows when react app initializes?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

[image: this is the syntax of error]

[2]: the error TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null while
creating a new react app

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, I had to download a different version of node.js(an older version of it)